# Display duration in formnat 1 h, 5 min or 1 h 5 min

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, time

I'd like to display the duration of a task (`1 h`, `5 min` or `1 h 5 min`).
I have the following code:

```
h = h != 0 ? h : '';
min = min != 0 ? min : '';
total = hours + ' h ' + minutes + ' min';
```

But this obvioiusly shows somethig like `h 5 min` if the duration is `5 min`. How can I solve this?

Comment: `if ( ... ) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: @Andreas no one liner for this?

Comment: If you're not familiar with `if ... else ...` then you might want to ignore any "one-liner"-solution...

Comment: @Andreas I thought I could shorten my code a little bit with a one liner.

Comment: Your question asks about a completely different problem which could have been solved with a simple `if ... else ...`

Comment: @Andreas absolutely not, James and freedomn-m solved it perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the units with the hour/minute values in your ternary conditions.

```
h = h ? h + ' h' : '';
min = min ? min + ' min' : '';
total = h + min;
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should *not* mix up / reuse variable types if you can help it.  Sure, you can, but it'll bite you later.

```
h = h != 0 ? h : '';
```

`h!=0` implies that `h` is a number before this line and a string *or* a number after - you then can't use that `h` again as the original number.

In this case, or the case of a few lines, that may not matter - but it's a slippery slope.

As you're already using the conditional operator, you can include it on your output directly without the need for reassigning the variables.

```
total = (h == 0 ? "" : h + " h") + (m == 0 ? "" : " " + m + " min");
```